Clarification: Stalks of the structure sheaf of an affine scheme (and more generally, stalks of a sheafification)
Given a presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ of abelian groups on a space $X$, let us take the definition of the sheafification as in Hartshorne (compatible germs). Now, one way to show that the stalks are isomorphic to the stalks of the original presheaf is to map a section (collection of compatible germs) to the germ of the local section from which it arises around a point, this will induce a map from the stalk of the sheafification (described via disjoint union of modules modulo equivalence relation). This involves some simple checking.
Now, another, maybe more natural (if not the same),  choice for such a map is to just evaluate the section, which lands in the stalk at that point, by construction of the sheafification. Now, here is a proof sketch for why it satisfies the universal property:
A collection of maps $\mathcal{F}^+(U)\to H$ induces a collection $\mathcal{F}(U)\to H$, upon composing with the canonical map, this induces a unique map $\mathcal{F}_x\to H$, and this also makes the original diagram for $\mathcal{F}^+$ commute. Uniqueness follows from uniqueness of $\mathcal{F}_x\to H$.
Now, this also shows that for a ring $A$, the the stalk of the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec }A}$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ is $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
Now, so far I have only made some statements, what's the question? It's about what is `natural'. Consider the following instances:
Refer Hartshorne Prop. II.2.3.b : For a homomorphism $\phi:A\to B$ of rings, the induced map $\mathrm{Spec} B$ to  $\mathrm{Spec} A$ is a morphism of locally ringed spaces.
In the proof, he gives a map $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec }A}$ to $f_*\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec }B}$ and claims that the induced map on stalks is simply the local homomorphism induced by $\phi$. Now, this is true very nicely if we take the map to be the evaluation described above (since $s'(\mathfrak{q})=\phi_\mathfrak{q}\circ s\circ f (\mathfrak{q})=\phi_\mathfrak{q}\left( \Phi_U(s) \right)$ where $\Phi_U:\mathcal{O}(U)\to A_{f(\mathfrak{q})}$ is the evaluation). Is this why he claims it is true?
Refer Hartshorne Prop. II.2.3.c : Every morphism of loc. ringed spaces $(f, f^\#):\mathrm{Spec}\ B\to \mathrm{Spec}\ A $ arises in the above way.
In the proof, he claims that the local homomorphism induced on stalks commute with the localization homomorphisms, but all we know is that it commutes with the morphisms induced by the isomorphism $\Gamma(\mathrm{Spec}\ A, \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}\ A})\cong A$. Again, this follows if one takes the stalk map to be the evaluation described above (Send $a\in A$ to the section $s_a$ mapping the prime $\mathfrak{p}$ to $a/1$ in $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$, then compose with evaluation, this composition is precisely the localization map). Same question, is this why Hartshorne claims that it is true?
Taking it to be that works so incredibly nicely that it's difficult to think that it could be otherwise, anyway, thanks in advance

What is your $H$? The target space of the evaluation map $ev_p$ at the prime ideal $p$ must be $A_p/p$.

Sorry if that was unclear, that is just an arbitrary abelian group, to demonstrate that the $\mathcal{F}_x$ with the evaluation maps does indeed satisfy the universal property for the colimit.

Stalks of a sheaf of abelian group $\mathcal{F}$ might not be a constant abelian group $H$. It can change by the place you evaluate.

Perhaps I was not clear enough. I am not claiming that H is the stalk. I am claiming, a collection of maps $F^+(U)\to H$, where U is an open containing x, making the restriction diagrams commute, induces a unique homomorphism $F_x\to H$, showing that $F_x$ is the direct limit.

Oh ok. You mean that $F_x$ satisfies certain universal property.
What is the definition of the evaluation map $\Phi_U$?

And in the last paragraph, $\Gamma(Spec(A),\mathcal{O}{Spec A})=A$ seems like more of a definition of the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}{Spec A}$. For $a\in A$, the evaluation of $a$ at the prime ideal $p$ must be its value in $A_p/p$, which is an integral domain.
